# Is it practical to distinguish aleatoric uncertainty from epistemic uncertainty?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, bayesian-network, uncertainty

I know the difference between the two, but don't know if it is practical to tell them apart technically.
[image]

Say, I have trained a deep neural network and I use [some techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65748064/3552975) to get the posterior predictive distribution and capture both the two types of uncertainty. But without knowing if the input features have left the knowing grounds(extrapolation) or not, how do I determine two distributions(CPDs) with the same variance belonging to aleatoric or epistemic uncertainty?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that I train a classification model with 10 classes. I run a MC dropout model tens of times. The aleatoric uncertainty is expressed in the distribution across the classes, which is zero if one class gets a probability of one. The epistemic uncertainty is expressed in the spread of the predicted probabilities of one class.